# .NET XML Serializer with Japanese chars in username

Tags: .net, xml, unicode, xml-serialization

We are having a problem whenever our application makes use of the XML 
Serializer, when we are logged in as a user who has a username containing 
Japanese characters.

We have prepared a sample application that tests the serializer on its own:

```
              TestClass myClass = new TestClass();
              myClass.MyString = "Hello World!"; 

              using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
              {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(
                          typeof (TestClass));
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, myClass);
              }

              MessageBox.Show("Serialization Complete!");
```

Where TestClass is defined as:

```
  [Serializable]
  public class TestClass
  {
        public string MyString { get; set; }
  }
```

When Serialize() is called, the following exception is reported:

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class 
(result=1).
error CS0016: Could not write to output file 
'c:\Users\??????\AppData\Local\Temp\qas_8hjs.dll' -- 'The directory name is 
invalid. '

Note the '?????' where the user name should be displayed.

We have tested this using a user with an English character-set based name, 
and it is fine.

Is there something we have neglected to set up (for example any environment 
or AppDomain settings?) or is this a bug in the XML serializer?

I know this is pretty specialist, but any insights whatsoever would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [SGEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(VS.80).aspx) to avoid it having to create the dll at runtime?

However, I would be tempted to log that as a bug on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Note that the SGEN approach won't help web-servers:

> These generated assemblies cannot be
>   used on the server side of a Web
>   service. This tool is only for Web
>   service clients and manual
>   serialization scenarios.